# Oh my zsh: No message if command not installed

Tags: zsh, fedora, oh-my-zsh

I don't know if it's a problem with zsh or oh my zsh.
If i try to run a command that is not installed, no error message is shown.

Example oh my zsh:

```
➜  ~ svn -version
➜  ~
```

Example bash:

```
[mrclrchtr@fedora ~] $ svn -version
bash: svn: command not found
[mrclrchtr@fedora ~] $
```

Does anybody have an idea why there is no error message in zsh?

Edit:
Here is my abridged ~/.zshrc

```
# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
# export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH

# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
  export ZSH=/home/mrclrchtr/.oh-my-zsh

# Set name of the theme to load. Optionally, if you set this to "random"
# it'll load a random theme each time that oh-my-zsh is loaded.
# See https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Themes
ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"

# Which plugins would you like to load? (plugins can be found in ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/*)
# Custom plugins may be added to ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/
# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
# Add wisely, as too many plugins slow down shell startup.
plugins=(
  git
)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
```

**Edit 2**

```
➜  ~ trap
➜  ~ whence -c command_not_found_handler
command_not_found_handler () {
    runcnf=1 
    retval=127 
    [ ! -S /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket ] && runcnf=0 
    [ ! -x /usr/libexec/packagekitd ] && runcnf=0 
    if [ $runcnf -eq 1 ]
    then
        /usr/libexec/pk-command-not-found $@
        retval=$? 
    fi
    return $retval
}
➜  ~
```

Comment: This is not normal. Please post your `.zshrc` so we can see what's wrong with it.

Comment: I added all parts, which are not commented out

Comment: Can you please post the output of the commands `trap` and `whence -c command_not_found_handler`?

Comment: I added the output

Comment: hi @mrclrchtr did you find the problem?

Comment: Hi @sencer no i could not find a solution.

Comment: I just found - for my case at least. Uninstall command-not-found, command-not-found-data, python3-commandnotfound, get the deb files from an earlier release and install these.